# TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'getitem' django url part

Tags: django

hi I started to learn django newly. I want to upload a photo to my website. I did the other parts but in urls part I got error like this. What should I do?

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from bildirge.views import contact, home
from bildirge.urls import *
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()
from bildirge.views import ProfileImageView, ProfileDetailView,  ProfileImageIndexView

urlpatterns = patterns[
url(r'^contact/', contact),
url(r'^home/', home),
url(r'^$', ProfileImageIndexView.as_view(), name='home'),

url(r'^upload/', ProfileImageView.as_view(), name='profile_image_upload'),
url(
    r'^uploaded/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ProfileDetailView.as_view(),
    name='profile_image'),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And error is

> TypeError: 'function' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a stray `patterns` before the opening of the list of URLs. Remove that.